# Adding digits depending on the length of a String

Tags: vb.net

I want a code in vb.net with something like the following, my problem is at the last statement where I'm failing to create a 16 digits string from the missing digits which is equal to C.

```
Dim A as string
Dim B as a string
Dim C as integer
if len(A) = 16 then
   B = A
elseif Len(A) > 16 then
   B = first 16 digits of A, 'ignore the rest if the digits'
elseif len(A) < 16 then
   C = 16 - len(A)
   B = A & digits equal to count of C 'Making Len(B) = 16'
else
end if
```

Comment: Please add sample input and desired output for each case.

Comment: Try the StrDup method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.strdup

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding

Comment: Or [`& new String(char, repeat)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_). How to sub-string a string should be somewhere in the notes of the programming course.

Comment: @MarkL The Strings class in in the Visual Basic namespace. It is better to use the String class which is more mainline .net

Answer (score 0):

I have used the .net String class which is part of the .net Framework in the System namespace.

String.Length is a property of a String. It replaces the old VB6 Len method.

String.Substring has several overloads. The one I used here has 2 integers as arguments. The first one is the starting index and the second one is the length of the string to be returned.

String.PadRight has two arguments. The first is an Integer providing the total lenght of the new string. The second is a Char provided the character to pad with. The little c following differentiates a String from a Char literal for the compiler.

You can see all the String methods and properties at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PaddedString As String = Get16String(TextBox1.Text)
    Debug.Print(PaddedString)
End Sub

Private Function Get16String(Input As String) As String
    Dim B As String = ""
    If Input.Length = 16 Then
        B = Input
    ElseIf Input.Length > 16 Then
        B = Input.Substring(0, 16)
    ElseIf Input.Length < 16 Then
        B = Input.PadRight(16, "0"c)
    End If
    Return B
End Function
```